# anova_test (rstatix) Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases

Tags: anova, rstatix

I am trying to conduct a two-way repeated measures ANOVA using the dataset below (df2):

```
# A tibble: 20 × 5
   `Lateral Preference` Student `1st Grade` `2nd Grade` `3rd Grade`
   <chr>                  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 Left                       1          22          26          34
 2 Left                       2          24          25          30
 3 Left                       3          18          22          24
 4 Left                       4          20          23          27
 5 Left                       5          30          36          40
 6 Left                       6          23          27          35
 7 Left                       7          23          24          29
 8 Left                       8          19          21          23
 9 Left                       9          29          24          28
10 Left                      10          32          38          40
11 Right                     11          27          29          34
12 Right                     12          28          34          36
13 Right                     13          25          26          28
14 Right                     14          23          26          30
15 Right                     15          26          34          36
16 Right                     16          25          27          29
17 Right                     17          30          31          35
18 Right                     18          21          25          28
19 Right                     19          24          25          28
20 Right                     20          30          33          35
```

The following manipulations were performed to prep df2 for ANOVA:

```
df2 = df2 |> 
  pivot_longer(3:5, names_to = "GradeLevel", values_to = "ReadingScore") |>
  rename(Handedness = `Lateral Preference`) |>
  convert_as_factor(Handedness, Student, GradeLevel)
df2$GradeLevel = fct_inorder(df2$GradeLevel)
```

However, when I try to run the ANOVA within Handedness and GradeLevel

```
df2 |> anova_test(dv = ReadingScore, 
                  wid = Student, 
                  within = c(Handedness, GradeLevel))
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
> 0 (non-NA) cases

Everywhere I look says it is due to NAs in my data, but all(is.na(df2)) returns FALSE, so I don't know what is wrong.

I have tried reloading my packages in the order "rstatix, tidyverse" as has been suggested, and rearranged the data by GradeLevel, Student, or Handedness. There are no NA values in my data.

UPDATE: I found the root of my problem. I was getting an error because the factors in 'Handedness' did not apply to every student, so therefore the "within" parameter couldn't compare the students' reading score to the different handedness value. What I needed to do was a mixed-method ANOVA, shown below:

```
df2 |> anova_test(dv = ReadingScore, 
              wid = Student, 
              within = GradeLevel, 
              between = Handedness)
```